# Close program after pressing "Close"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm facing some problem, when i start my program i run WindowForm1 and then user had to type password and username if it's correct then it's exit form1 and run form2. If user type wrong password or username then he had chance to retype this or he can Close program with the "red X" - which works ok. 
But when the password and username were correct and he had Form2 running when he press "close" application still run in the background. 
Can you please give me any info how to close this app when he press close on Window Form 2.

Comment: Post your code that you have written. Makes answering 1000% easier.

Comment: `public void CloseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { this.Close(); }` :D

Comment: A simple `this.Close();` or `NameOfObj.Close();`

Comment: Use `Application.Exit()` in `WindowsForm2_FormClosed` Event.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Environment.Exit` on the closed event handler:

```
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.FormClosed += Form2_FormClosed;
}

private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

[Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Exit terminates an application immediately, even if other threads are
>   running. If the return statement is called in the application entry
>   point, it causes an application to terminate only after all foreground
>   threads have terminate

You can also use [Application.Exit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.exit(v=vs.110).aspx) which:

> Informs all message pumps that they must terminate, and then closes
>   all application windows after the messages have been processed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, just didnt know about FormClosed. I'v used Application.Exit

Answer (score 1):

On form close method write this.

```
Application.Exit();
```

Comment: I always hate this command, and feel its the last way I want to handle things